# What does 'make much muster' mean in the following context?

Tags: word-usage, literature

This excerpt comes from [Uncle Tom's Cabin](http://utc.iath.virginia.edu/uncletom/utfihbsa17t.html)(270),

> 'No; I slept, ears and all, for an hour or two, for I was pretty well tired; but when I came to myself a little, I found that there were some men in the room, sitting round a table, drinking and talking; and I thought, before I ***made much muster***, I'd just see what they were up to, especially as I heard them say something about the Quakers.'

I tried Google, Dictionary.com and Merriam Webster and the most apt meaning they give is 'a formal gathering of troops;rally'. My question is do we still use 'muster' in the same fashion or it has fallen out of date today?

Comment: Yes, we muster courage. In the passage, the speaker is hesitant to gather himself up fully awake and call unwanted attention to himself

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you for commenting. So people would say 'make a muster' to mean 'fully wake up'?

Comment: I hear the word used as a verb only (to muster something that needs a lot of energy to gather up).  A boy might muster his courage to ask a girl to dance. You might muster your courage to ask your boss for a large raise in salary.

Comment: @YosefBaskin As a noun, something can most commonly _pass muster_ if it's good enough.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You are quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "muster" as a noun originally meant, essentially, a group of people.

(All definitions from OED)

> 1. The number of people or things assembled on a particular occasion; an assembly, a collection.

Next OED provides a definition related to the act of calling together such a group, usually in a military context:

> 2. a. Chiefly Mil. An act of calling together soldiers, sailors, prisoners, etc.; an assembling of people for inspection, exercises, etc., or an act of counting or enlisting people into (esp. armed) service; a roll-call. Also (Austral.): a census (now hist.).

This definition has a footnote related to the exact structure used in the quoted text.

> **to make** (also take) **a muster**, to assemble and count soldiers, etc. ***to make (one's) muster***: to muster or review one's forces; **to make an effort**;

This is further elaborated to extended use beyond military application in definition 2b.

As Jeff Morrow's answer points out, this sense related to gathering a military assembly is being used metaphorically to describe "gathering courage" or "gathering effort."

Answer (score 2):

"Muster" is no longer a common word in English. It basically means "to gather together" and was often used to describe the assembling of an army or militia. It is mostly now used in a figurative sense: "muster one's courage," "muster one's wits," "muster one's resources." The general sense of those stock phrases is "currently preparing to act" in distinction to "currently acting."

Answer (score 1):

In Pearl Buck’s, The Good Earth (p. 35), the expression is used as follows:

> So long as Wang Lung and his father were poor and scantily fed the uncle made muster to scratch about on his land and gather enough to feed his seven children and his wife and himself.

Given the context, the expression appears to have the sense  discussed in Answer 3 of “to rouse oneself” or “to make the effort”.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442355)

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because I think it is both relevant and interesting. Thanks, R. Green, and welcome to English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 0):

Henry Gates & Hollis Robbins, editors, [*The Annotated Uncle Tom's Cabin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bSaWhPgOOpMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Uncle+Tom%27s+Cabin%22+annotated&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP87bz16HWAhWH3oMKHRYKC7QQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22muster%22&f=false) (2007), offers this footnote about the expression "to make muster," in connection with the posted quotation:

> Ironically, a military term for "show oneself."

If this is accurate, it probably comes from the the military notion of appearing at muster (that is at the assembling of one's fellow troopers when one's unit is called together). The extended sense is along the lines of "make an appearance."

Interestingly, there is another instance of "making a muster" in [*Uncle Tom's Cabin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=K-o9AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22making+a+great+muster%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP6_H72qHWAhVFsVQKHfh9DzQQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22making%20a%20great%20muster%22&f=false), where the sense of "showing oneself" or "making an appearance" seems less relevant:

> Carriage sticks fast, while Cudjoe on the outside is heard **making a great muster** among the horses. After various ineffectual pullings and twitchings, just as the senator is losing all patience, the carriage suddenly rights itself with a bounce, two front wheels go down into another abyss, and senator, woman, and child all tumble promiscuously into the front seat; ...

From this second instance, it seems that Stowe may have had her own particular understanding of the meaning of "make a muster" and that her meaning was closer to "make a commotion" or "make an extended effort" than to the meaning suggested by Gates & Robbins, though I have no doubt that their meaning is historically accurate. In any case, "make a commotion" or "make an extended effort" would work for both excerpts from *Uncle Tom's Cabin*—albeit it to a somewhat lesser degree in the case of "make an extended effort" as applied to the "before I made much muster" quotation in the posted question—whereas "show oneself" works only for the excerpt quoted in the posted question.